# What is the "./" operator in Unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In order to run a specific program saved in my home directory, I have to invoke it using the "./" command. What exactly does the command do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`./` is not a command, it is part of a path. When you run a command, the executable must either be in a directory listed in your `$PATH` environment variable, or you must specify the path explicitly. `./cmd` means run the executable `cmd` in the current directory.

Comment: and you can put `./` if you really wanted to.(not advised)

Comment: @JID I don't understand your comment - what do you mean?

Comment: It would appear that half my comment has disappeared. It was supposed to say `put ./ in your PATH variable`.

Comment: @JID ah right, makes sense now. There's some discussion of the potential risks of adding `./` to your `$PATH` on [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65700/67817).

Answer (score 3):

`.` is the current directory.

`./file` is a relative path to the file from the current directory whereas `file` is just a bare name that the shell needs to search for (in the `$PATH)`.

It is no different (in concept) from `/bin/sh`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`./` is not a command.  Strangely `.` is a real directory name, it is linked to the current directory.  So, your current directory has (at least) *two* names, the one you normally use, and `.`.  All directories have this, even on Windows.

The `/` happens to be the directory separator character used on Linux and UNIX.

Let's say your current directory is `/home/pete`.  You could run your program by saying:

```
/home/pete/program_name
```

or:

```
./program_name
```

They mean the same thing.  Of course you don't always need that with programs like `ls`, this is because those programs reside in a directory which is mentioned in the `PATH` environment variable.  `echo $PATH` to see that.

I said that directories have at least two names.  If there is a sub-directory then within the sub-directory it is also known as `..`.  Therefore a directory has two names (called *hard-links*) plus one for every sub-directory.  Check out the `ls -l` command:

```
mkdir adir
ls -ld adir
drwxr-xr-x  2 clivedarke  staff  68  6 May 17:25 adir
ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x+ 74 clivedarke  staff  2516  6 May 17:25 .
```

See the second column?  2 for a new directory (adir).  You can see that my current directory (`.`) has 74 names (hard-links) and so that means 72 subdirectories.